# Unity C# scripts when edited in Vs Code, do not offer auto completion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

Whenever I write code for my game in visual studio code, there is no autocompletion offer...

For example, in the picture below, "Transform" doesn't even exist.

I have already downloaded unity recommended extensions: Debugger for Unity, Unity Snippets, Unity Code Snippets, Unity Tools. And it didn't work even if I remove them.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Edit -> Preference -> ExternalTools

[image: Preference]

then chose your External Script editor
[image]

then there you go

incase it's still not working, it's probably because your visual studio does not have the unity developer package, go to your visual studio installer, then modify and check the unity package thinggy.

or download the extension if u using visual studio code

Comment: Yeah, I probably don't have the Unity Developer Package because I have already set up vscode in "Preferences".
Thank you for helping

Comment: Your welcome.
Sorry to be rude, but can you at least verified my answer :)
I have a really bad reputation ._.

Comment: There you go I did it :)

(It isn't rude to ask for something)